# GITK with Angular 2 has issues on redirects using fragments (# hash)

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

The Google Identity Toolkit workflow has issues if integrate with Angular or other javascript frameworks.

Angular is using URL fragments (#) to navigate among the views. It is also possible to navigate using the HTML5 style and avoiding to use hashes but unfortunately Angular 2 has an issue in properly handling fragments, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595.

Because URL fragments are internally used by Angular and similar frameworks it is preventing GITK to work properly in some circumstances:

During the login workflow if the user is successfully authorized by a third party sing-in service the user is redirected back to the GITK widget page.

The redirect URL will include a state parameter. In case of Twitter or Facebook the state parameter is added as query param to the URL (e.g. ...login/?state=AFD_5tlxzU...).
However other services like Google Account are adding the state parameter has fragment to the redirect URL (e.g. ...login/#state=AFD_5tlxzU...).

Due to the fact that Angular is using the URL fragments to navigate, the state fragment (e.g. ...login/#state=AFD_5tlxzU...) of the redirect URL is removed by the framework preventing GITK widget to successfully complete the authentication.

Is there any option to instruct Google Accounts or GITK to use query params instead of fragments? Also I was wondering what is the rational of using fragments instead of query params for the redirect URL?

Answer (score 1):

*I am answering to my self.*

One way to solve the issue as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7215#issuecomment-216195959) is to move the sing-in logic outside the Angular routing paths.

For instance by creating a separate static .html file that is only responsible for the sing-in. An alternative solution would be to use ng2-ui-router.

Comment: Just wondering how exactly did you solve that in ng2 ui-router?